# Pronto VS ASAP; Which one is quicker/the quickest?

Tags: word-usage

> - I'll collect my daughter from school **pronto**, due to the political chaos that has just started in our town.
> - I'll collect my daughter from school **ASAP**, due to the political chaos that has just started in our town.

Which one is quicker/the quickest?

Comment: There's no one right answer to this question. It's a matter of opinion. There's not a chart of "words for quickly" rated by how quick. Personally, I would never use "pronto"... it sounds weird...

Comment: **Pronto** is almost mock-serious.  You might say you have to get to the bank pronto before it closes, but you wouldn't use pronto to describe how quickly you would act to rescue someone from a dangerous situation. Not unless you were Indiana Jones.

Comment: I heard it often from a BE speaker who used it for non-dangerous situations.

Comment: Makes sense. I don't think you would hear "I'll collect my daughter..." in AmE.

Comment: @user3169, yes you'd prefer to use 'pick up' right?

Comment: Yes, "pick up" is fine, also simply "(go) get".

Answer (score 2):

Both of these terms are slang terms for "quickly". They're about equally strong, you can't say that one implies a more quick behavior than the other.

What's different is their origins and what they imply about the kind of person who would say them.

*ASAP* began as army slang in the 1950's (according to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=asap)) but it has been taken up by the business world, and you nowadays most likely hear it from someone working in the corporate world.

*Pronto* dates from the 1850's ([same source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pronto)) and it's usage has faded in my experience over the past few decades. You're most likely to hear it in a Western movie, or used by a fictional character as a way to indicate how old-fashioned they are.

Comment: I heard it often from a BE speaker who used it for non-dangerous situations.

Comment: When I worked in an office where we sent items out to be punched on tape, the first time I put ASAP in the "when required?" box. One of my colleagues pointed out that this would put it _after_ the requests which had specific deadlines!